# Render large screen version on phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using boostrap 3 and all the website contents contain classes like
`col-sm-X`, `hidden-xs`, and the collapsed menu, etc...

The customer wants the website to look on the mobile devices exactly like it looks on the PC screen. Is there a way I can change something that doesn't require me to change the whole source code so I can render the same website on PC and Mobiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think removing this line would accomplish that:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```